# How to use tree with grep and find to locate files by name?

Tags: files, grep, find, search, tree

How can I use `tree` and either `grep` or `find` in conjunction to find, for example, `csv` files using ".csv" as a file extension:

```
├── ./Videos
├── ./vscode
│   ├── ./vscode/foo.csv
│   ├── ./vscode/Hello.java
│   └── ./vscode/helloworld.ps1
└── ./xxxx

5850 directories, 29132 files
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ tree -f | grep *.csv
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

just for example.  See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/10212192/4531180

---

looking for a specific file:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ tree -f / | grep 'note.xml'
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

not quite sure where `eXide` put the [file](http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/dashboard/index.html):

[image: eXide]

also tried:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ find /home/nicholas/ -name *note.xml*
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ find -iname "note.xml"
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

so bit perplexed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `find` instead.

```
find . -iname \*.csv
```

Comment: how can I search the entire hard drive?  Here, I just have the one hdd.  I want to start at `/` and look everywhere.  `find / -iname \*.foo`?

Comment: yes. And if you run `man find` you'll learn about all the other things it can do.

Comment: fair enough, reading the fine manual.  I was also looking at, I think, the `wholename` switch.